# button to Writing actual date and hour in selected cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted  to create function to write in selected cell, the actual date and hour, like writing manually the formula "=now()" in cell. but through a button.

Something like that, but actually doesn't work, nothing happen.

```
function botao(value) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var date = setValue('=now()');

  return date

  // Returns the active cell
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  // try to write date to the active cell as a value.
  cell.setValue(date);
}
```

Comment: This [web page](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/) describes exactly how to do what you want. Including halfway down the page to insert the current timestamp in the selected cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What about [shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)?

[image: Shortcuts]

---

#### If you need a script then:

```
function setDate() {

    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
    var date = new Date();

    cell.setValue(date);
}
```

---

#### An explanation of your code:

```
function botao(value) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Can be shortened to SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // Unnecessary if we call getActiveCell() from
  // the spreadsheet instead of the sheet

  var date = setValue('=now()');
  // This will likely give an error of something
  // like 'cannot find function setValue([string])'

  return date
  // Using return ends the function, all code below here is unreachable

  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  // You can get the active cell from the spreadsheet instead
  // of the sheet to reduce your calls

  cell.setValue(date);
  // Even if the variable 'date' stored '=now()', it's just text.
  // You'd have to use setFormula() instead.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is it.